# How do I merge two columns exactly and fuzzy merge one column?

Tags: r, dplyr, match

I currently have two datasets that I would like to merge:

```
year <- c("2002", "2002", "1999", "1999", "1997", "2002", "2005", "2008")
state <- c("TN", "TN", "AL", "AL", "CA", "TN", "NY", "NC")
name <- c("Brass; Smith", "Joe", "Christopher", "Bob; Holland", "Wayne", NA, "Joseph A. Freeland", "")

df1 <- data.frame(year, state, name)

year <- c("2002", "2002", "2005")
state <- c("TN", "TN", "NY")
versus <- c("Carl Brass", "Joe", "Freeland")
color <- c("Blue", "Red", "Yellow")

df2 <- data.frame(year, state, versus)
```

I want to combine `year` and `state` exactly. I then want to match `name` and `versus` in `df1` and `df2` respectively. I also want the fuzzy match to occur before the `;`.

I want an output that looks like this:

```
year <- c("2002", "2002", "1999", "1999", "1997", "2002", "2005", "2008")
state <- c("TN", "TN", "AL", "AL", "CA", "TN", "NY", "NC")
name <- c("Brass; Smith", "Joe", "Christopher", "Bob; Holland", "Wayne", NA, "Joseph A. Freeland", "")
versus <- c("Carl Brass", "Joe", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Freeland", NA)
color <- c("Blue", "Red", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Yellow", NA)

df3 <- data.frame(year, state, name, versus, color)
```

I tried the following:

```
f <- function(n,v) {
  wrds = stringr::str_extract_all(n, "\\b\\w*\\b")[[1]]
  sum(sapply(wrds[which(nchar(wrds)>1)], grepl,x=v,ignore.case=T))>0
}

df4 <- left_join(df1, df2, by=c("year","state")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(versus:=if_else(f(name, versus), name, NA_character_))
```

But I keep getting this error message:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `versus = if_else(f(name, versus), name, NA_character_)`.
ℹ The error occurred in row 8.
Caused by error in `sum()`:
! invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

I'm not sure what is going on and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that you have `NA` in your data, but you do not deal with `NA` in your function `f`...